# set pdf header with html code (having a image reference) using HTMLWorker?

Tags: java, itext

I want to set PDF header with html code. Following is the code:

```
public void createHeader(Document pdfDocument, String k) throws IOException {

    k = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg"></body></html>";
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(k);      
    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(pdfDocument);
    htmlWorker.parse(reader);
    HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(reader.toString()), false);
    document.setHeader(header);

}
```

What is the problem with my code? Should I add anything?

Comment: I tried at main content it is working. But I want to set the image coming from html to pdf header.

Comment: One of the problems with your code is that you are using `HTMLWorker`. You should use `XMLWorker` instead.

Comment: Another problem with your code is that you have quotes within quotes. You should escape the quotes inside your string.

Comment: XMLWorker is available in newer versions of itext. We are using older version. I do not want it to update as other dependencies are there on itext. Please suggest some solution using older version of itext.

Comment: I will not suggest a solution that involves `HTMLWorker` because I am an iText employee and that would go against the goals and principles of the company.